# "IndentationError: Expected an indented block" but when I fix it, I get "Syntaxerror: Invalid syntax"

Tags: python, syntax-error

I cannot seem to figure out why I am getting these error messages. I have tried retyping my code multiple times and it just won't work.

```
def check_if_win():

  row_winner = check_rows()
  diagnal_winner = check_diagnals()
  column_winner = check_columns()
  if row_winner:
    #Row Win
  elif column_winner:
    #Column_Winner
  elif diagnal_winner:
    #Diagnal Win
  else:
    winner = None
  return
```

Comment: The error is on the ```elif column_winner:``` by the way.

Comment: There must be at least one line of actual code indented underneath the `if` and `elif` statements.  A comment isn't enough.

Comment: even `pass` or ellipsis  (`...`) will do.

Comment: Thats where the syntax error starts add some print statements under each if elif etc

Comment: Please show your code and its complete traceback with a [mcve].

Comment: @John Gordon the error will be on the first ``elif`` after the first ``if``, because the ``if`` itself is not problematic. The line that comes after ``if`` is where the problem (indentation) lies.

Comment: @Karina Oh, that's true!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
def check_if_win():

    row_winner = check_rows()
    diagnal_winner = check_diagnals()
    column_winner = check_columns()
    if row_winner:
      #Row Win
        None
    elif column_winner:
      #Column_Winner
        None
    elif diagnal_winner:
      #Diagnal Win
        None
    else:
        winner = None
    return None
```

Will work